# How to compare the count of each table in two different databases?

Tags: database, oracle

I have two databases: db1 and db2 (db2 was completely empty). I was copying all the db1 to db2 but the progress was interrupted and I need to know which tables are still left to copy. How can I compare the count of each table in these two databases to know which tables I still have to transfer?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to loop through the data dictionary and generate some dynamic SQL which executes a count for each table.

I have assumed you're only transferring one schema. If that's not true, or you're not connecting as the target schema, you'll need to use ALL_TABLES instead of USER_TABLES, and include the OWNER column in the driving query and the dynamic query too.

```
declare
    n pls_integer;
    stmt varchar2(32767);
begin
     for r in ( select table_name from user_tables order by table_name ) loop
         stmt := 'select count(*) from ' || r.table_name;

         -- uncomment the next line to debug errors
         -- dbms_output.put_line(stmt); 

         execute immediate stmt into n;
         -- you may wish to only display empty tables
         -- if n = 0 then 
         dbms_output.put_line(r.table_name || ' = ' || lpad(n, 10));
         -- end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

One would hope that your data copying process was clever enough to commit only completed tables. If so you only need to run this on DB2. Otherwise on both.